# Dependancy Property with Observable Collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
    public IEnumerable<Location> Locations
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Location>)GetValue(LocationsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocationsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Locations", typeof(IEnumerable<Location>), typeof(userControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));  




  public class Location
    {
        public db.Location DbLocation { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<db.Person> DbContactsInLocation { get; set; }
    }

    Locations = myDataContext.Locations
       .Where(l => l.Active == "Y")
       .OrderBy(l => l.Name)
       .Select(l => new Location { 
               DbLocation = l
               **DbContactsInLocation = l.PersonLocations.Select(pl => pl.personLocation.person)**
                }).ToList();
```

I'm getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<myDataContext.Person>'` to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`<myDataContext.Person>'`
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert your LINQ query into an `ObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor. Try this:

```
DBContactsInLocation = new ObservableCollection<myDataContext.Person>(l.PersonLocations.Select(pl => pl.personLocation.person).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your linq query in an [`ObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerabele<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx).

```
DbContactsInLocation = new ObservableCollection<db.Person>(
  l.PersonLocations.Select(pl => pl.personLocation.person)
)
```